# how to replace mousemove event to my robotmove event

Tags: pixi.js

I have a desktop robot device, which connects to a web browser(chrome) using ble(Bluetooth low energy), I have created a custom event in js code to catch some motion values when the robot moves.

but in pixijs all events are base on mouse move, how can I extend it to adapt my scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/v6.0.0/packages/interaction/src/InteractionManager.ts#L858

I think that you would need to create your own version of `InteractionManager` as a plugin, and modify that method `addEvents()`. You would need to listen to your custom event which is fired when the robot moves.

```
// instead of:
self.document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onPointerMove, true);

// do like this:
self.document.addEventListener('my_custom_robot_move', this.onPointerMove, true);
```

etc.

Normally the `InteractionManager` is registered here: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/fe7b2191e0311b8174a012366ff21c8e2b6dc153/bundles/pixi.js/src/index.ts#L30 - so you would need to call something like this at beginning of your js code (just after the pixi scripts are loaded probably):

```
Renderer.registerPlugin('interaction', MyInteractionManager);
```